# Generic partial view: how to set a generic class as model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics

I'm trying to build a generic grid view in an ASP.NET MVC application.

Let me explain with some code:

```
public interface ITrustGrid<T>
{
    IPagedList<T> Elements { get; set; }
    IList<IColumn<T>> Columns { get; set; }
    IList<string> Headers { get; }
}
```

This is an interface of a class that allows me to set columns and expressions in my controller.

I pass implementations to a partial view like this:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("SimpleTrustGridViewer", ViewData["employeeGrid"] as TrustGrid<EmployeeInfoDTO>); %>
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to make the partial view that renders the grid generic.

In other words, I want to turn this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<ITrustGrid<EmployeeInfoDTO>>" %>
```

into something like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<ITrustGrid<T>>" %>
```

=> How can I make my partial view generic in the most simple way?

**EDIT:**

I solved this by using a TrustGridBuilder that has a public TrustGrid GetTrustGrid() method which returns a non-generic TrustGrid. The TrustGrid contains strings instead of linq stuff. So I execute the linq in the GetTrustGrid() method and put the strings in a TrustGrid object.

Thanks for everybody to help me on the right track.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to do it like that. The reason is the `.aspx` will generate a class that you don't have much control on it and you can't add a generic parameter to it. I guess the most straightforward way is to pass it as `object`.

Comment: hmm I tried that, but wasn't able to figure out how to cast it back to something useful.

Comment: You pretty much can't cast it to anything useful, but you still can use it as dynamic object.

Answer (score 7):

You could make all your model types that you would pass into this partial inherit from a base class/interface that establishes the basic behavior that would be used by this partial view and accept any object of that class/interface type, or just have the view accept any type of object and then use reflection to base your partial view behavior off of.

EXAMPLE:

```
public interface IDisplayModel
{
    string DisplayText{get;set;}
    string ImageUrl{get;set;}
    string AltText{get;set;}
}

public interface ITrustGrid<T> where T : IDisplayModel
{    
    IPagedList<T> Elements { get; set; }    
    IList<IColumn<T>> Columns { get; set; }    
    IList<string> Headers { get; }
}

<%@ Control Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<ITrustGrid<IDisplayModel>>" %>
```

Naturally, your `IDisplayModel` would vary based on your desired behavior.  This would then allow you to pass in anything to this partial that implements this base interface to establish general behavior.

Comment: Could you give a short example on how to achieve the reflection solution?

Comment: Added example and changed the contol inherits attribute to accept "ITrustGrid<IDisplayModel>"  Hopefully this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks but I don't like about this solution that I have to make every class implement the IDisplayModel interface.
I would prefer a solution where I can add something in the partial view to make it work. Perhaps I could add a Type member to my ITrustGrid interface? I'm trying something like that at the moment, but I'm quite new at this generic stuff :)

Comment: You can use reflection in the view and have your view model ITrustGrid<Object> and then use reflection to determine type and display logic accordingly inside your partial but this would make the view more bloated than I would prefer.  Good luck.

Comment: Argh, I can't figure it out.. Been trying all kinds of things but can't get the Type of Model. I tried adding a 'Type' member to my interface but that didn't work either..

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mehrdad, as far as I know it isn't possible to make generic views. In one of my projects, I used an interface much like your one, and then passed delegate functions to the view that handle the specific rendering of each item.

For instance, I would have used a non-generic view data class with an additional field:

```
public interface ITrustGrid {
    IPagedList Elements { get; set; }
    IList<IColumn> Columns { get; set; }
    IList<string> Headers { get; }

    Func<object, string> ElementRenderer { get; }
}
```

In your main view you'll prepare the view data:

```
<%
ITrustGrid data = (ITrustGrid)ViewData["employeeGrid"];
data.ElementRenderer = new Func<object, string>(delegate(o) {
    var employee = (Employee)o;
    //render employee
    return html;
});

Html.RenderPartial("SimpleTrustGridViewer", data);
%>
```

While in your grid partial you'll process the grid as usual, and then call the delegate to render each single cell:

```
<%
foreach(var element in ViewData.Elements){
    %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=ViewData.ElementRenderer(element) %></td>
    </tr>
    <%
}
%>
```

Of course, the code above only renders a single cell for each element, you'll have to create a slightly more complex delegate to render multiple columns (or pass in an array of delegates, one for each column).

I think this would be one of the cleanest ways to do it, albeit a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

@ Lck:

I'm doing something like that in my controller:

```
var columns = new List<IColumn<EmployeeInfoDTO>>
                  {
                      new Column<EmployeeInfoDTO>("Full name", e => string.Format("{0} {1}", e.FirstName, e.Name)),
                      new Column<EmployeeInfoDTO>("Examination date", e => e.ExaminationDate.HasValue? string.Format("{0} days ago", currentDate.Subtract(e.ExaminationDate.Value).Days) : "Unknown")
                  };

var employeeGrid = new TrustGrid<EmployeeInfoDTO> { Columns = columns, Elements = GetEmployees(currentPageIndex)};

ViewData["employeeGrid"] = employeeGrid;
```

So in my partial view I can do this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<ITrustGrid<EmployeeInfoDTO>>" %>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <%
                foreach (string header in Model.Headers)
                    Response.Write(Html.Th(header));
            %>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <%
            foreach (var element in Model.Elements)
            {
                Response.Write("<tr>");
                foreach (var column in Model.Columns)
                    Response.Write(Html.Td(column.ValueExpression(element)));
                Response.Write("</tr>");
            }
        %>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="pager">
    <%= Html.Pager(Model.Elements.PageSize, Model.Elements.PageNumber, Model.Elements.TotalItemCount)%>
</div>
```

As you see, none of the code in my partial depends on the Type used. So I still think there's a simple solution.

Comment: Since your partial doesn't depend on the type used, can you just use Object?  ITrustGrid<Object>?

Comment: I get "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Helpers.TrustGrid`1[LinqToSqExample.Model.EmployeeInfoDTO]' but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Helpers.ITrustGrid`1[System.Object]'." when calling the partial view with TrustGrid<EmployeeInfoDTO>

Comment: Model is null when I call the partial with TrustGrid<object>

Comment: I get the same result as you describe above if I inherit from ITrustGrid<customtype> on TrustGrid (concrete class).  If I change my TrustGrid inheritance to ITrustGrid<Object>, then it works for me.

Comment: hmm will try that tomorrow. Thanks for checking it out.

Comment: I have altered my code. TrustGrid<T> now is TrustGridBuilder<T> and it has a .GetTrustGrid method that returns a TrustGrid instance. The TrustGrid instance has a IEnumerable<string> Header and a IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> Elements member.