# ASP.NET MVC Manually Applying DisplayFormat

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, generics, asp.net-mvc-uihint

I have a model with a property which is a generic looking something like:

```
class PairedData<T>
{
    public T Value {get;set;}
    public bool IsValid {get;set;}
}
```

In the model I have:

```
class SomeModel
{
    [UIHint ("PairedInt")]
    public PairedData<int> SomeInt {get;set;}

    [UIHint ("PairedDateTime")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"]
    public PairedData<DateTime> SomeDate {get;set;}
}
```

Then in my Display Template for PairedDateTime I have:

```
 @model PairedData<DateTime>

 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Value)
```

The problem is that the DisplayFor doesn't apply the date format. The reason is obvious enough - the DisplayFormat attribute is on SomeDate, not on the Value property, so is not being read.

So the question is, is there a way to tell the DisplayFor to read the attribute from somewhere else? Or is there a way to manually pass the same information to DisplayFor within the Display Template? Or is there a way to apply the attribute to Value only in the DateTime instantiation (unlikely, I think)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to format this on view if you are sure this will always be a DateTime:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Value, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new {maxlength=10})
```

This works, but I would recommend you the approach suggested by Daryl and bkaid here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6733855/1638261

Comment: Thanks - that'll do in this specific situation. I'd still be interested in a more general approach.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't seem to work. The string parameter is a template name, not a date format.

I don't see anything in the linked article about formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The DataType Annotation will give you the date format by default mm/dd/yyyy and the input for this will be a drop down list and combined with the DisplayFormat should give you the results that you are looking for.

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Comment: The problem is I'm using a generic so although that annotation is appropriate for the DateTime instantiation, it's not for, say, int.

The question remains - how do I apply different attribute to different instantiations of the generic?