# How to pass generic parameter to partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generic partial view: how to set a generic class as model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875085/generic-partial-view-how-to-set-a-generic-class-as-model)

I am trying to build common functionality using generic types but got stuck with below scenario.

View Model

```
public class DeleteForm<T>  
{
    public LogInfo Ticket { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public DeleteForm() {
      Ticket = new LogInfo();
    }

    public DeleteForm(T viewModel) : this() {
      ViewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public T ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string name)
{
   return View("index", new DeleteForm<List<Users>>(new List<Users>());
}
```

List Screen

```
@model DeleteForm<List<Users>>
//gridview displays list of users
@Html.Partial("revisionwindow", Model)
```

Partial View

```
@model DeleteForm<T> <---Its not working

@Html.EditorFor(o=>o.Ticket)
@Html.EditorFor(o=>o.Id)
```

Comment: I tried by passing object and dynamic but it doesn't seem to work. For ex: @Html.Partial("revisionwindow", (object) Model) but in the partial view, I am unable to cast it back to the DeleteForm<T>.

Comment: I tried by using interface too but in the posted link interface contains independent properties. But in my case, I need to initialize the list based on a specific type i.e., T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a model to view, it has to be strongly-typed (particular type).
So `SomeClass<T>` type won't work. Instead of generic type a base class could fill
your requirements. What I mean is:
View Model

```
public abstract class Form
{
    public Form()
    {
        Ticket = new LogInfo();
    }
    public LogInfo Ticket {get; set;}
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
public class DeleteUsersForm: Form
{
    public DeleteUsersForm(IEnumerable<Users> users):base()
    {
        this.ViewModel = users;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Users> ViewModel {get; set;}
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string name)
{
    return View(new DeleteUsersForm(new List<Users>()));
}
```

List Screen

```
@model DeleteUsersForm
//displays list
@Html.Partial("revisionwindow", Model)
```

Partial View

```
@model Form

@Html.EditorFor(o=>o.Ticket)
@Html.EditorFor(o=>o.Id)
```

Answer (score 7):

use dynamic model instead.
your partial view can look something like this :

```
@model dynamic

 @{
      var myModel = (DeleteForm<List<Users>>) Model;
 }

@Html.EditorFor(o=>myModel.Ticket)
@Html.EditorFor(o=>myModel.Id)
```

hope this help.

Comment: I am trying to replace List<Users> with generic type so that it will be common across all modules. T can be list or other custom view model which contains the list. So var myModel = (DeleteForm<List<Users>>) Model, doesn't work in my case. Instead it should be (DeleteForm<T>) Model; which is giving error.